# Cannot find Interop.Word

Tags: .net, office-interop, .net-assembly

I recently received a project and at the moment cannot launch it.
The problem is the absence of the `Interop.Word` assembly. I tried to include `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` but the solution is not building. I could not find the assembly `Interop.Word` in my computer. How can I find it or what software it comes with?

PS. All my attempts to search were redirecting to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`. My os is Win 7 x64 Home Premium, MS Office 2010 Russian is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Interop.Word` assembly is an automatically-generated wrapper around a COM DLL. You need to recreate it: delete the old reference, go to 'Add Reference', select the COM tab and select the Microsoft Word component.